# Tip of your current branch is behind remote, but when I git pull it says it is up to date?

Tags: git

I am trying to `git push` my local branch to a remote branch, but I run into:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:bmlltech/dd-services.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Now, I understand the error, and when I do a `git pull <remote_branch_repo>`, and I get:

```
From github.com:....
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

So I am a bit confused about the error... my local branch is up to date with the remote branch but I still get the above error?? Any ideas?

1. git status: On branch ED-6024_reference_query_for_listing_with_index_constraint
   nothing to commit, working tree clean
2. git branch -r:  NOTHING is returned
3. git push
   fatal: No configured push destination.
   Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository using

   git remote add

and then push using the remote name

```
git push <name>
```

4. git pull:
   There is no tracking information for the current branch.
   Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
   See git-pull(1) for details.

   git pull

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> ED-6024_reference_query_for_listing_with_index_constraint
```

Comment: Q: Did you try `git add .;git commit -m "..."`?  Or, alternatively, `git reset --hard`?  It sounds like you're "stuck" until you update your local branch (either commit, or abandon your changes).

Comment: OK I tried `git add .` and then `git -m "..."` but it says there is nothing to commit!

Comment: So weird... I also did `git reset --hard` followed by trying to push but I get the same error?

Comment: Maybe you're inadvertently trying to "pull" from a *different* branch? Run the following commands.  [Edit] your post, and copy/paste the commands and the results:  1) `git status`,  2) `git branch -r`, 3) `git push`, 4) `git pull`.  Do NOT explicitly specify a branch in your "push" or "pull".  See also: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. When you say `pull from a different branch` - how do I pull from a branch? Up to this point everytime I have done a git pull, it has been `git pull <SSH_of_repo>` and this has worked. (Is this what you mean by 'pull from a branch'?)
But recently, others in my team have pushed to master branch and I did an `Update branch` on my branch.

Comment: I meant (for troubleshooting purposes only!) "just type `git pull`.  DON'T type `git pull <SSH_of_repo>`, `git pull <remote_branch_repo>` or any other variant you might be trying."  The same for `git push`. It sounds like your project has different branches (perfectly normal, of course!) ... and you're inadvertantly pushing/pulling to the WRONG branch(es).  Your FIRST step is to be able to reliably commit, push and pull.   to/from your local "default" branch. Your NEXT step is to sort out which branch you actually need to be working with, and reliably commit, push and pull with respect to it.

Comment: Now please do what I asked above: [Edit] your post, and copy/paste: 1) `git status`, 2) `git branch -r`, 3) `git push`, 4) `git pull`. Do *NOT* explicitly specify a branch in your "push" or "pull". Also read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Does your repo have different urls for push and pull on that remote ? `git remote -v`

Comment: Also, if you want to have a clearer view of your repo's history after you pulled : `git log --oneline --graph HEAD FETCH_HEAD`